# How to merge two line in a file into one by specified condition in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file which is exported from mysql using command select into outfile escaped by "\"... However, there are newlines in some fields which result in broken lines, namely a record in mysql is split into two lines in exported file. After careful analysis, I find the line which is broken ends with "\". So I want to merge lines like this into its next line. How can I do this?

example input:

```
hello
world\
Thank
you\
are
awesome
```

output:

```
hello
worldThank
youare
awesome
```

The file is a bit large, which can be 10 GB or so.

Comment: can you provide an example of input and a desired output please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed 'N;s/\\\n//;P;D;' file
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `awk`:**

```
awk '/\\$/{sub(/\\$/,"");printf $0; next}1' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `/\\$/` look for record/line ends with `\`
- `sub(/\\$/,"")` substitute, `\` with null
- `printf $0; next` print record without row separator, and go to next line
- `}1` `1` at the end does default operation `print $0`, so line which did not skip will be printed as it was.

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat infile
hello
world\
Thank
you\
are
awesome

$ awk '/\\$/{sub(/\\$/,"");printf $0; next}1' infile
hello
worldThank
youare
awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided an example, but if you have something like the following, then... It works in GNU sed (I'm on OS X)

```
$ cat /tmp/sql
select * from usr \
join org on usr.org_id = org.org_id \
where usr_id = 'xyz'

$ sed -z 's/\\\n//g'
select * from usr join org on usr.org_id = org.org_id where usr_id = 'xyz'
```

Comment: However gsed is not a built-in command in centos7... And when the file is big enough, cat command may be not a good idea.

Comment: Use `sed` instead, on linux it's GNU. And what's exactly the problem with `cat` and big files? Though it's a different question :)

Comment: Host can not allocate that large memory if the file is big enough.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156577/top-not-showing-the-memory-usage-of-cat can give you an idea of how `cat` actually does its work. Though in your case it was not necessary, I admit. You can just run `sed -z ...` to achieve the same result

Answer (score 0):

Another one using `awk` by manipulating output record separator

```
$ awk '{ORS = sub(/\\$/,"") ? "" : "\n"} 1' ip.txt
hello
worldThank
youare
awesome
```

Clear `ORS` if the substitution succeeds (removing `\` at end of line) else assign the usual newline character

With `GNU awk`, simply use `\` followed by newline character as record separator. And empty string as `ORS` since these characters have to be just deleted

```
$ gawk -v RS='\\\\\n' -v ORS= '1' ip.txt
hello
worldThank
youare
awesome
```

With `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/\\\n//' ip.txt
hello
worldThank
youare
awesome
```

Newline character from input line is not removed like `sed/awk` (requires option `-l`). So the logic simplifies to removing the newline character along with `\` at end of line